# Piping input to stdin prevents read_line() blocking

Tags: rust, stdin

I'm trying to write a terminal program that pipes in a CSV file, parses the records, then launches a quiz based on them. My issue is that once I pipe the file into my command line program using `io::stdin()`, I can not longer use `io::stdin().read_line()` to get user input because it stops blocking or waiting for user input. Below is the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    println!("Please enter input");
    let mut user_input = String::new();
    stdin.read_line(&mut user_input).expect("Failed to get input");
    println!("The input was {}", user_input);
}
```

Using `cargo run` causes the normal blocking behavior. Using `echo 'Hello World' | cargo run` causes `read_line()` to no longer block anywhere throughout the program.

I assume it's not a bug and just how stdin works. Can anyone explain the fine detail of this behavior and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Assuming your program has a way to determine where the CSV file ends, you could launch it as `cat quiz.csv - | cargo run` which will concatenate `quiz.csv` to the standard input (represented by `-`).

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it's not a bug and just how stdin works.

Correct. Assuming you're ok with targeting Unix systems, a workaround is to open `/dev/tty` explicitly:

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    // read piped stuff from stdin...

    // read interactive input from the user
    let mut input = BufReader::new(File::open("/dev/tty").unwrap());
    println!("Please enter input");
    let mut user_input = String::new();
    input.read_line(&mut user_input).expect("Failed to get input");
    println!("The input was {}", user_input);
}
```

Note that getting the input from the user this way is not the idiomatic way to write command-line programs, because it cannot be automated. Instead, consider supporting command-line options, which crates like [clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap) make convenient.